# Where should I put @EnableAsync annotation

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, blazeds

I need to send a email in async way while saving the data into DB.

My approach was like this.

```
//I have tried with service layer annotating.But not worked. 
@EnableAsync 
class MyService{
 public String saveMethod(List listOfData){
    mail.sendEmailQuote(listOfData);
    mail.sendEmailWorkflowTaskAssignment(listOfData);
    myDao.saveData(listOfData);
 }
}
```

I need to perform following methods in @Async way. Where should I put @EnableAsync annotation. This is not a Schedule related thing. This is happen when user click save button. Application is used flex spring blazeDS. There is no controller written by my self.

I have used @Async annotation in my code for following 2 methods. Those are in class call Mail.

```
@Async
sendEmailQuote(listOfData){}

@Async
sendEmailWorkflowTaskAssignment(listOfData){}
```

Could you help me to find where should I put @EnableAsync ?

[I refer this sample](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

Answer (score 23):

`EnableAsync` is used for configuration and enable Spring's asynchronous method execution capability, it should not be put on your `Service` or `Component` class, it should be put on your `Configuration` class like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Or with more configuration of your `AsyncExecutor` like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

 @Override
 public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
     ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
     executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
     executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
     executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
     executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
     executor.initialize();
     return executor;
 }
 }
```

Please refer to [it's java doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) for more details.

And for the tutorial you followed, `EnableAsync` is put above `Application` class, which `extends AsyncConfigurerSupport` with AsyncExecutor configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
}
```

Comment: If you follow https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ step by step, it will work. The correct config would be: 1. `@Service` is above your `MyService` class; 2. `@Async` is above your method in `MyService` , 3. `@EnableAsync`, also with `@SpringBootApplication` be above your `Application` class. Or could you please post all your code already tried?

Comment: what if I want use it in spring project,not springboot project?

Answer (score 19):

Just make sure that @Async methods aren't called by the same class. Self invocation for proxy won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give light on some use case of @EnableAsync with @Async and Executor Framework.

You can use **@EnableAsync** in your any **configuration (@Configuration)** class as well as Your main class/Driver class of the **Application(@SpringBootApplication)**.

**@EnableAsync:** It indicates spring boot to enables asynchronous behavior for all that methods which are annotated with @Async.

**@Async:** This annotation is generally used over the method, which contains the logic related to Asynchronous task, like Sending Email, OTP, Service Messages, Etc.. This methods are generally a part of any Service or class which is annotated with @Service or @Component annotation.

**Executor Framework:** Generally we are preferring to use Executor framework to maintain threads and its lifecycle(creation, task assignment, etc..)

You can create a Bean of **ThreadPoolTaskExecutor** and can set the required properties like, core pool size, max pool size, queue capacity for tasks, **can set thread naming prefix for tracing**, set rejection handler (Exception for for denying the entry of in queue). Check the below snippet.

```
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4); //Generally it should higher than core pool size
    executor.setQueueCapacity(400);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Executor-Thread");
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler((r, exception)->sysout("Thread Queue is Full."));
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Hope this info will helps you.! Keep Learning.! Give up-vote if it helps...!